# Divide table raw into chunks in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with too long entries with 1s and 0s. For example I have table :

```
| Sent id.|   BoW.   |
|---------|----------|
|    1    | 10100101 |
|    2    | 00011110 |
|    3    | 10101111 |
```

I want to create new table which will divide column BoW. entries into some arbitrary length (in this case 4) and assigns chunk number.

```
| Sent id.| Chunk No. | BoW. |
|---------|-----------|------|
|    1    |     1     | 1010 |
|    1    |     2     | 0101 |
|    2    |     1     | 0001 |
|    2    |     2     | 1110 |
|    3    |     1     | 1010 |
|    3    |     2     | 1111 |
```

I beginner, tried to search in documentation, but without success. Maybe something like this, but with proper function:

```
CREATE TABLE Bow2 AS
  SELECT Sent_id,
         (Chunk+1) AS Chunk_No,
         BoW/div(4) AS BoW;
  FROM Bow1;
```

Answer (score 5):

One method that comes to mind is to use `generate_series()`:

```
select b.sent_id, chunk, substring(bow from (chunk - 1) * 4 + 1 for 4)
from (select b.sent_id, generate_series(1, 1 + floor(length(bow) - 1 / 4) ) as chunk
      from bow1 b
     ) b;
```

This method is flexible because it adapts to different lengths of `bow`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT SentId, chunk.id, SUBSTRING(BoW FROM chunk.v FOR 4) AS BoW
FROM (VALUES (1, 1), (2, 4)) AS chunk(id, v)
CROSS JOIN mytable
```

The query uses an in-line table containing the starting position of each chunk. The length is fixed and it is assumed to be equal to 4. You can adjust the query to suit your actual data.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bc294/4)

Comment: Thanks, it is what I want, but I need Chunk numbers to compare entries later.

Comment: @Masyaf I'm afraid I don't understand you.

Comment: I mean your answer displays SentId and Chunk, I need SentId, ChunkID and Chunk. Chunk it must increment every time chunk is created.

Answer (score 0):

Just as suggestion:

```
with recursive t(num, head, tail) as (
  select 1, substring('1234567890', 1, 3), substring('1234567890', 4)
  union all
  select num+1, substring(tail, 1, 3), substring(tail, 4) from t where tail > '')
select * from t;

 num | head |  tail   
-----+------+---------
   1 | 123  | 4567890
   2 | 456  | 7890
   3 | 789  | 0
   4 | 0    | 
(4 rows)
```